# lightGallery клик на кнопку не работает в safari > 9 версии, в сhrome все работает

Tags: jquery

```
buttonAlbumCard.setAttribute('data-counter',i);
for (let j = 0; j < everyAlbumPhotosLength; j++) {
            var o = {};
            o['src'] = eventsRESPONSE[i].photos[j].photo_url;
            o['thumb'] = eventsRESPONSE[i].photos[j].photo_url;
            imagesUrls.push(o);


        console.log($("button[data-counter='"+i+"']")[0]);
       $("button[data-counter='"+i+"']"[0]).on('click', function() {
           //работает в chrome , но не работает в safari 
           var lGallery = $(this).lightGallery({
               dynamic: true,
               dynamicEl: imagesUrls
           })
           lg.one("onCloseAfter.lg", function() {
               lg.data('lightGallery').destroy(true);
           })

        })
    }
```

Comment: Какие ошибки в консоли пишет?

Comment: дело в том что нет возможности установить сафари данной версии

Comment: И да, строчка `"button[data-counter='"+i+"']"[0]` это бред, приглядитесь повнимательнее

Comment: я извиняюсь за плохо составленный вопрос, у меня выше есть код , я его не добавил , динамически создается кнопка, к ней добавляется дата-аттрибут, и в цикле присваиваю к аттрибуту порядковый номер, и вот таким вот образом я вызываю нужную мне кнопку $("button[data-counter='"+i+"']"[0]), и это работает в хроме

Comment: Я не знаю, каким чудом оно работает в хроме, но эта строчка является бредом

Comment: не моглибы вы подсказать как лучше искать нужные мне кнопки до data- аттрибутам? раз данное решение бред..

Comment: Так же, как вы сделали это в console.log, в нём написан не бред

Comment: $($("button[data-counter='"+i+"']"[0]) ? я переписал это вот таким образом)) ?  или опять бред написал

Comment: Теперь дважды бред) Похоже, вы не знаете основ JavaScript и jQuery, иначе кусок кода `"']"[0]` вас уже давно смутил бы